# Get CLLocation coordinate from a method

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I follow a tutorial from http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/
to make an app to show user's current location.
It has a method called locationUpdate

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
    //locLabel.text = [location description];
    speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SPEED: %f", [location speed]];
    latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LATITUDE: %f", location.coordinate.latitude];
    longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LONGITUDE: %f", location.coordinate.longitude];
    altitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ALTITUDE: %f", [location altitude]];
}
```

How do i call location.coordinate.latitude outside this method?

Answer (score 1):

Make a variable of CLLocation in your .h File, and then set that variable when the location updates (in the below method).

`- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location`

Comment: like this `CLLocation *currentLat;` ?

Comment: yes that would be correct. remember to import mapkit in the .h

Comment: how do i assign it in viewDidLoad()

Comment: no in the method I posted in the answer `- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location`

Comment: please select this answer as correct if it has worked for you.